# Trouble installing python command, and "whereis python" command returns multiple paths

Tags: command-line, python

I am trying to get Ubuntu to recognize the 'python' command. I currently gives:

```
Command 'python' not found, did you mean:
command 'python3' from deb python3
command 'python' from deb python-is-python3
```

I believe part of the problem may be an error in a file path, so I used the `whereis` command to find where python is located on my pc. However, it returns multiple paths, which appear to be to different files related to at least two versions of python (2.7 and 3.8):

```
python: /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/lib/python3.8 /etc/python3.8 /usr/local/lib/python3.8 /mnt/c/Users/Lea/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python.exe /mnt/c/Users/Lea/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.exe
```

Does this mean I have somehow installed python incorrectly on my PC? For reference, I am using Windows 10.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1249306/edit) to show the actual output instead of a summary. Use copy/paste

Comment: @user535733 Thank you, I have done that.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `sudo apt get update` then run `sudo apt install python`

Comment: You can improve this answer by reminding the OP that Python2 support ends very soon. Time to migrate Python2 scripts!

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be worried by seeing multiple versions of python installed, it is often installed as a dependency by other programs. Have you ever installed it deliberately via `apt-get install` as suggested by Ekure Edem?

If you have and typing `python` still doesn't launch python, then I would suggest that you create a bash alias. I'll assume you want to use `python 3.8` for this example:

If you enter `alias python='/usr/bin/python3.8'` into a terminal, you should find that entering `python` will launch `python3.8`. Unfortunately, this won't persist after you close the terminal (or after you logout, depending on your settings).

To make the alias permanent, add `alias python='/usr/bin/python3.8'` to the file `~/.bash_profile`. This should be the fist file that is executed when you login, so It's where I put all my aliases.

**Friendly Reminder**

Python 2 is no longer supported and will start to develop issues (including security issues) as modules stop being compatible with it.

If you have any python 2 scripts you rely on, I'd recommend porting them to Python 3.